# How to add database data to Jquery control dynamically in ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0

I'm new to Jquery .I want to display daily reports in JQuery calender control but I'm failing to load data dynamically from data base any one please help me

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        defaultDate: '2014-11-12',
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        events: [
            {
                title: 'All Day Event',
                start: '2014-11-01'
            },
            {
                title: 'Long Event',
                start: '2014-11-07',
                end: '2014-11-10'
            },
            {
                id: 999,
                title: 'Repeating Event',
                start: '2014-11-09T16:00:00'
            },
            {
                id: 999,
                title: 'Repeating Event',
                start: '2014-11-16T16:00:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Conference',
                start: '2014-11-11',
                end: '2014-11-13'
            },
            {
                title: 'Meeting',
                start: '2014-11-12T10:30:00',
                end: '2014-11-12T12:30:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Lunch',
                start: '2014-11-12T12:00:00'
            }

        ]
    });

});
```

Then please tell me how to load this title and start dynamically from database in asp.net

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement rest service and call it using AJAX. The most common way is create `ApiController` (if you are using MVC) or add `ASMX Service` for `WebForms`. You also able to import `WebApi` to `WebForms` project via `NuGet`.

The full explanation is too long. I'll give you some snippets:

Configure route table. Insert `{action}` placeholder in `routeTemplate`

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Create ApiController method:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public List<CalendarEvent> GetEvents(int count)
    {
        return new List<CalendarEvent>();
    }
```

Call your api method with Jquery and get JSON:

```
        $.getJSON('http://yoursite.com/api/GetEvents', {
            count: 5
        }, function (data) {
            var jsonData = data;
        });
```

Comment: Isn't there any simple way by using simple for loop ?

Comment: @Lax_me if you want to fetch data from server you don't need loops. You need to call server method from client-side. Get jsondata and set it to calendar `events` property